# terraform remote-exec does not find aws command

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, terraform

HI I am try to run following terraform code

```
    provisioner "remote-exec" {

    inline = [
      "cd /home/ec2-user",
      "curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py",
      "sudo python get-pip.py",
      "pip install --upgrade --user awscli",
      "echo mokul",
      "aws --version",
      "echo mymsp",
      "eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)"

    ]
}
```

terraform can install pip and aws but cannot find aws command
Successfully installed PyYAML-3.12 awscli-1.11.107 botocore-1.5.70 colorama-0.3.7 docutils-0.13.1 futures-3.1.1 jmespath-0.9.3 pyasn1-0.2.3 python-dateutil-2.6.0 rsa-3.4.2 s3transfer-0.1.10 six-1.10.0

```
/tmp/terraform_760494262.sh: line 6: aws: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the installation of the aws command so after you run the `pip install --upgrade --user awscli`

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bash_profile
aws --version
```